# Replacing object in array with another object, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to push (splice) object from variable into array, but it causes an infinite loop, 
the point is to replace object in array with another object from React state.

```
handleDuplicate = (id, nextId) => {
  let items = [...this.state.items];
  let currentItem = this.state.items[id];
  if (items && currentItem) {
    console.log(currentItem); // --- logs object from react state properly
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].id == nextId) {
        items.splice(i, 1);
        // items.splice(i, 0, currentItem); // --- causes infinte loop
        items.splice(i, 0, { id: 111, test: "test" }); // --- runs ok
        i--;
        console.log(items);
      } else {
        console.log("---");
      }
    }
  }
  this.setState({ items });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` function to replace the item :

```
handleDuplicate = (id, nextId) => {
  const currentItem = this.state.items[id];
  const items = this.state.items.map(
    item => item.id === nextId ? currentItem : item
  );

  this.setState(prevState => ({items});
}
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. Just modyfied a little.
`handleDuplicate = (id, nextId) => {
  const currentItem = this.state.items[id];
  const items = this.state.items.map(
    item => item.id === nextId+1 ? currentItem : item,
  );

  this.setState({items});
}`